# error : java.lang.String cannot be cast to coldfusion.cfc.CFCBeanProxy anyone know about this?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Does anyone know about this error I get when I try to insert a foreign key value in my entry entity using ColdFusion 9 Hibernate integration?

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to  coldfusion.cfc.CFCBeanProxy
>
> Root cause :org.hibernate.HibernateException:  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to  coldfusion.cfc.CFCBeanProxy

Below is the code for my entity object and then for my user object..

Is there anything wrong with this?

**entry.cfc**

```
/**
* Entries Object
*/
component output="false" persistent="true"{
    property name="entry_id" fieldType="id" generator="uuid";
    property name="entryBody" ormType="text";
    property name="title" notnull="true" type="string";
    property name="time" fieldtype="timestamp";
    property name="isCompleted" ormType="boolean" dbdefault="0" default="false";
    property name="userID" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="userID" cfc="user";

    Entry function init() output=false{
        return this;
    }
}
```

**user.cfc**

```
/**
* Users Object
*/
component output="false" persistent="true"{
    property name="userID" fieldType="id" generator="uuid";
    property name="firstName" notnull="true" type="string";
    property name="lastName" notnull="true" type="string";
    property name="password" notnull="true" type="string";
    property name="userType" notnull="true" type="string";
    //property name="entry" fieldtype="one-to-many" type="array" fkcolumn="userID" cfc="entry";

    User function init() output=false{
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: output="false" is not really needed for component in script style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
property name="user" type="User" fieldtype="many-to-one" fkcolumn="userID" cfc="User";
```

Because the property should be type User, not the ID?  In CF-ORM/Hibernate, there's no way to just set FK.  You must...

```
entry = EntityNew("Entry");
user = EntityLoadByPK("user",1);
entry.setUser(user);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Henry I get I get this different error message now:

Error Type: ColdBox.plugins.BeanFactory.PopulateBeanException : [N/A]
Error Messages: Error populating bean guestbook.model.entry with argument USER of type class java.lang.String.
If the component name is specified as a type of this argument, it is possible that either a definition file for the component cannot be found or is not accessible.
The user argument passed to the SETUSER function is not of type user.

Comment: that means, you should remove user (it is really userID:String) from coldbox's RC.  Then set User yourself after populate is called.

Comment: sorry to ask but where do i remove the user from ?

Comment: getPlugin("beanFactory").populateBean() populate the bean from RC (i.e. FORM + URL scope).  So since your rc.user is currently a string that contains userID, and populateBean() is calling setUser(rc.user) which caused the exception.

Comment: Either: rename your view/form to use userID instead of user, so populateBean() will not complain.  Or, backup the rc.user as userID, delete from rc, before you call populateBean().  Then finally: entry.setUser(entityLoadByPK("user", userID));

Comment: I had a friend of mine help me following your example and it worked thank you very much.

Comment: thanks do you know where is the option for me to mark this as answered ?